# php date function return wrong time. why?

Tags: php, datetime

I am using IST in my code. for this thing I declared gloabal variable as below code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$IST=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$config['IST']=$IST;
```

In my other files I am calling this variable as

```
$IST = $config['IST'];
$time = $IST;
echo " Current time is $time";
```

I am getting wrong time. If current time is 2015-02-03 15:41:14 it is showing 2015-02-03 16:41:14

How to fix this issue?

I have updated my server time zone to Asia/Kolkata.

Comment: check what timezone you getting on other file?

Comment: Check out if your source works on other servers.. here a sample on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/3af1vB)

Comment: @Dwza : Thanks for your suggestion. I found that my code is working on the other server. I found issue with server's clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your valuable suggestions. I apologize. I did't check my server's clock. It was all about server's clock. Once I set my server's clock to correct time, issue resolved.

I apologize again and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

'Asia/Kolkata' [exists only since](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php) PHP 5.2.6.
Which PHP version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');